# Fatal error: Call to undefined method PHPMailer::IsSMTP() in /path/ on line 39

Tags: phpmailer, fatal-error

I have a simple Mail post script with Phpmailer Master that i downloaded from github.

i have a fatal error on my script. But i cant find the solution. I googled but i didnt find any source for this error.

My script looks like this;

```
<?php require_once("ayarlar.php"); ?>
<?php
if(($_POST["kullanici"]==$kullanici)and(isset($_POST)))  // Authetnticating Admin E-Mail Address
{
/* Şifremi Unuttum Mail Gövdesi */
$ad="Company Name";
$mesaj ="
<style type='text/css'>
    body{
        font-family:'Verdana', Geneva, sans-serif;
        font-size:10px;
        }
    table{
        font-size:14px;
        }
</style>
<h2>ADMIN PASSWORD</h2>
<hr>
<table style='width: 100%;'>
  <tr style='width: 100%;'>
    <td valign='middle' style='height:30px;width:50%;'>KULLANICI ADI: $kullanici</td>
  </tr>
  <tr style='width: 100%;'>
    <td valign='middle' style='height:30px;width:50%;'>ŞİFRE: $parola</td>
  </tr>
  <tr style='width: 100%;'>
    <td valign='middle' style='height:30px;width:50%;'>Lütfen Bu Epostayı Güvenli Bir Yerde Saklayın ve/veya Yazdırın</td>
  </tr>
</table>";
/* Şifremi Unuttum Mail Gövdesi */
/* Php Mailer Class Mail Göndermek İçin */
require_once("../inc/phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php");
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->CharSet  = "UTF-8";
$mail->AddAddress   ("someone@example.com","Company Name");
$mail->Subject      = "ADMIN PASSWORD";
$mail->Body         = "$mesaj";
$mail->Port     = 26;
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->Host         = "mail.example.com";
$mail->SMTPAuth     = true;
$mail->Username     = "someone@example.com";
$mail->Password     = "password";
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->From         = $kullanici;
$mail->FromName     = $ad;
$mail->Send();
/* Php Mailer Class Mail Göndermek İçin */
echo "<script>
    alert('Şifreniz Başarılı Bir Şekilde Eposta Adresinize Ulaştırılmıştır');
    window.location.href='http://www.example.com/admin-password';
    </script>";
}
else
{
echo "<script>
    alert('Hatalı Eposta Adresi');
    window.location.href='javascript:history.back()';
    </script>";
    exit();
}
?>
```

And i got following error:

Fatal error: Call to undefined method PHPMailer::IsSMTP() in /path/ on line 39

39 Line: $mail->IsSMTP();

Any suggestions?
Thanks For Helps.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have found the solution. Update my phpmailer library.